# Joomla upload zip and run in plesk

Tags: php, joomla, plesk

I try to host a site in `plesk` created with `joomla`.

I have installed joomla from Applications -> Joomla Install.

I can log in to the backend interface and see the general by default joomla template.

However in plesk in Files -> httpdocs where the site exist I have upload my joomla work from my local disk and extract it and their are all my files.

What should I do to configuration.php file in order to make the public url to see the results from the content I uploaded, or in other files?

I mean I have a zip file with the joomla content. I uploaded to http docs and extracted but in the public url I receive error. Why this is happening?

I noticed that index.php was overwriten when I openned the joomla from the application and after that I can't understand what changed.

Answer (score 2):

Joomla consists of files and a database.

One of the easiest ways to transfer a website is to use the free or paid version of Akeeba Backup which backs up the files and the database into one file. You can then use the free Akeeba Kickstart utility to restore the files and the database on the target location.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have rep points to comment, which is why this is posted as an answer. Sorry!

Can you give a little more information? You installed Joomla from the Plesk panel, so you should have all of the Joomla code files and directory structure. What is the "joomla work" you want to upload -- a complete site like Neil's answer I think assumed? Graphics files? Text documents? If it's artwork or the like, it would go in your "media" folder under the Joomla document root (httpdocs I would guess), and be accessible through the media manager.